# How to backup old magento onto new Magento on a different subdomain

Tags: magento-1.9, backup

I'm trying to design a new theme on my Magento so I created a test.***.com.au sub-domain to try it out on.
I want the old data/pics onto the new one to see how it all looks, but after trying to perform a backup in the Backend of my original install. It says "loading" and loops for what feels like eternity (I left it for 4 hours, still looping). Is there a way I can backup through cpanel or FTP? Or maybe a script I'm unaware of?

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 1):

Normally the timeouts are an issue with using the backup portion in the Magento admin.  Ultimately you may have to get down into the lower levels and use SSH to use some Command line statements to get what you need.

Magento has a good Wiki article detailing this process.

- https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024841/Moving+Magento+to+Another+Server

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou very much, going to try it now :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to SSH into my web server as it's a shared hosting plan. I looked into VPS plans and it seems a little out of our budget at the moment. Is there any other ways that you know of?

Comment: Sorry unfortunately you may need to ask your hosting provider for help, some offer control panels you can access to give a try.  Or perhaps they can SSH into the server to get what you need.  Normally low budget hosting doesn't work well with Mtagento. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/24196/69 While its not impossible it requires lots of customizations and tweaks to get it to run fast enough to be usuable. It also depends on who you are hosting with also.